# How to return Firebase document property using Angular Firestore (Angular 7)?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get Firebase document property based on this model:

[image: UserModel]

I've already found a document using the following code:
[image: get document]

//Users - collection name, uid - document uid.

Next, I'm trying to get isAdmin property using the following line of code:

[image: Get property]

In the results I receive undefined.

How it can be resolved? I need to return `isAdmin` property value, but I don't get how to do it.

Comment: Your are using async code. The isAdmin parameter is probably `undefined` when you return it because the subscription is not resolved at this point.

Comment: Try out directly `user.isAdmin` instead of `user.payload.data().isAdmin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very easy:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.auth.user$
    .pipe(
      switchMap(fireuser => this.userService.get(fireuser.uid).snapshotChanges()),
        map(document => document.payload.data().isAdmin) 
    )
}
```